# chemfig: merged molecules bond and name

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have two questions:

1. How can I draw a [smooth bond](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102655/joining-atoms-in-chemfig-two-adjacent-molcules) instead this arrowed one?
2. How can I write the molecule name (benzoyl peroxide) through `\chemname{}` under the two-merged molecules?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([:-60]=O)([:60]-@{a}O))-=-)}
\qquad
\chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C([:240]=O)([:120]-@{b}O))=-=-=-)}
\chemmove{ \draw[red,dotted] (a)--(b); }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\chemname{ % <--- group both molecules
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([:-60]=O)([:60]-@{a}O))-=-)}
\qquad
\chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C([:240]=O)([:120]-@{b}O))=-=-=-)}
}{Benzoyl peroxide}
\chemmove{ \draw[-,red,dotted] (a)--(b); } % <--- just put - on \draw arguments
\chemnameinit{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to write a single structure in Chemfig

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([:-60]=O)([:60]-O-[0,,,,dotted,red]O-[:-60]C(=[:-120]O)-[0]*6(=-=-=-)))-=-)}}{benzoyl peroxide}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]