# Generate png images of chemical structure using LaTeX, dvipng and chemfig

Tags: png, chemfig

How to generate `.png` images of chemical structures using `LaTeX`, `dvipng` & [`chemfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) ?

What packages need to be included ?

Is there any reference article for same ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: You may want to consider [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/) if you are on the Mac.

Comment: Is there any unix command which provides list of package which need  to be included in document for using "chemfig" ?

Comment: I'm using Linux CentOS

Comment: include `\RequirePackage[log]{snapshot}` before `\documentclass{article}` to see dependencies of `chemfig` in `.log` file. See [`snapshot` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snapshot). Have a look at for eg: [cgnieder's answer using chemfig](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102587/15717). Use options `[convert,border=2]` to [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class and run `pdflatex --shell-escape chem-file-example.tex` to get `.png`. See Martin Scharrer's answer to [Better resolution of uploaded pictures Q at meta.tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2436/15717)

Comment: @user1952498 if it works i shall make my comment as answer to make it answered question to reduce the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 1):

Include `\RequirePackage[log]{snapshot}` before `\documentclass{article}` to see dependencies of `chemfig` in `.log` file. See [snapshot documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) for more options.

Have a look at code example by [cgnieder's answer using chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102587/15717) that uses `chemfig` and `standalone`package.

Use options `[convert,border=2]` to `standalone` class and run `pdflatex --shell-escape chem-file-example.tex` to get `.png`.Refer [Martin Scharrer's answer to Better resolution of uploaded pictures Q at meta.tex.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2436/15717) for full steps.