# Get depth from a generated PNG with chemfig package

Tags: chemfig, baseline, latex-2-png

I generate PNG images from latex code to display in web/mobile applications. The general flow is:

1. Client makes an API call with the formula I should render
2. I wrap the formula in a preamble and run latex on it
3. From the generated .dvi I run dvipng with --depth

This process gives me a PNG image and the depth information and has been working fine for a while. Now I want to add the ability to render chemistry formulas, so I added chemfig package, and this is where the issue arises.

There are some answers over the internet like [here](http://nongnu.13855.n7.nabble.com/dvipng-and-chemfig-td197705.html) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114169/generate-png-images-of-chemical-structure-using-latex-dvipng-and-chemfig) advising to use pdflatex with chemfig and then another tool to convert from PDF to PNG, once just using dvipng won't produce correct images.

**Generated with dvipng**

[image]

**Generated with pdflatex + convert**

[image]

So I can render formula properly. The question is: is there a way to get image depth in this second flow?

The tex snippet to generate the images is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{yhmath}  % for \wideparen
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[active,textmath,tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}$\displaystyle \chemfig{A-B}$\end{document}
```

EDIT:
Using the suggested solution to write the information to another file I've got an empty file. Adding `\immediate` to writes it is not empty anymore, but all values are 0.0pt.

The full source is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{yhmath}  % for \wideparen                                                                                                                                                    
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[active,textmath,tightpage]{preview}

\setatomsep{2.0 em}    % 'Fixed Bond Length'                                                                                                                                             

\makeatletter
\global\let\tikz@ensure@dollar@catcode=\relax
\makeatother

\newsavebox\frm
\sbox\frm{$\displaystyle \chemfig{A-B} $}
\newwrite\frmdims
\immediate\openout\frmdims=\jobname.dims
\immediate\write\frmdims{depth: \the\dp\frm}
\immediate\write\frmdims{height: \the\ht\frm}
\immediate\write\frmdims{width: \the\wd\frm}
\immediate\closeout\frmdims

\begin{document}
\usebox\frm
\end{document}
```

Comment: using Linux, after the convert you can use `file` or `exiv2` as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670013/fast-way-to-get-image-dimensions-not-filesize and parse the output from that.

Comment: @Marijn But this would return the image depth in order to compute the baseline?

Comment: @ThiagoLewin assuming the _depth_ is the same as the height, then yes :)

Comment: @Marijn depth is the distance from the bottom of the image to the baseline. An entire description can be seen at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40977/confused-with-tex-terminology-height-depth-width

Comment: `chemfig` uses TikZ, which does not render in DVI files because it uses specials not understood by any DVI viewer (and by `dvipng`).

Comment: @egreg Do you know if there is another way to get the image depth or baseline without using dvipng?

Comment: using the `standalone` class and running it through `pdflatex` and then `convert` (imagemagick) on the PDF might be a solution.

Comment: @daleif But doing this way, can I read the depth or the baseline of the image?

Comment: Not really. Once the pdf is made, that information is lost.

Comment: @daleif Okay, but do you know if there is a way to get this information?

Comment: Nope. I get why you need it, but you need some really deep control to access that. Perhaps some of the box logging can be processed to give information relevant to the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure height, width, and depth within LaTeX and supply the information in an extra file. After pdflatexing the following document,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newsavebox\frm
\sbox\frm{$\displaystyle\chemfig{A-B}$}
\newwrite\frmdims
\openout\frmdims=\jobname.dims
\write\frmdims{depth: \the\dp\frm}
\write\frmdims{height: \the\ht\frm}
\write\frmdims{width: \the\wd\frm}
\begin{document}
\usebox\frm
\end{document}
```

you get, in addition to the pdf file, a text file with extension `dims` that contains the required information.

```
depth: 0.0pt
height: 6.83331pt
width: 37.29172pt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I trying to use it, but my `.dims` file is empty. I'm still trying to make it right, but you have any ideas why this can be happening?

Comment: @Aspirina What does the log file say? Any error messages? How does the source file look like?

Comment: I edited my question with more info. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Aspirina The culprit is the `preview` package. Why do you load it?

Comment: good catch! It was a legacy from our previous approach. It is working now. Thanks again.